# Como puedo eliminar el último elemento de una pila empleando un arreglo primitivo

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

quería hacerles una consulta

tengo una clase llamada pila que usa un vector de 50 posiciones para almacenar objetos de tipo proveedor, pasa que dichos debo eliminar el ultimo objeto de este vector, pero no puedo ya que se me genera un error de que el objeto es nulo.

```
public class Pila {

    public int top;

    Proveedor[] vector;

    public Pila(Proveedor[] vector) {

        top = -1;
        this.vector = vector;
    }

    public void eliminarNodo() {

        if (top != -1) {

            for (int i = top; i >= 0; i--) {

                if (i == 0) {

                    if (vector[i] != null) {

                        Proveedor proveedor = vector[i];
                        Pelicula[] peliculas = proveedor.getCola();

                        if (peliculas[0] != null) {

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La pila contiene registros de Peliculas");
                        } else {

                            vector[i] = null;
                            top--;

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha eliminado el último registro de la pila");
                        }

                    }

                    break;
                }

            }
        }

    }


}
```

la referencia del vector si está bien hecha, por lo que el error es debido al tema del manejo del top que es el índice.

Este es el error que se genera. agradezco cualquier ayuda para solucionarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Algún motivo para no usar la clase `Stack`?

Comment: no se puede, debe hacerse de 0

Comment: es parte de una tarea de la universidad donde debo usar arreglos primitivos y imitar el comportamiento

Comment: Pero... si o si necesitas usar `array ?, porque esto se puede hacer sin ellos y queda mejor

Comment: también solicita el uso de arreglos primitivos

Comment: tienes alguna idea de cómo arreglarlo? te lo agradecería mucho según yo solo es hacer un if para que entre aquellas posiciones que no son nulas, pero aun así me sigue tirando el mismo error.

Comment: Hola Isaac, en tu clase **Proveedor**, cada vez que agregas uno nuevo, la variable **top** ese aumentada, es la que te indica la posición dentro del array, del último proveedor, el problema es que no estás pasando esa variable a tu clase **Pila** por lo que, en ella, **top** es siempre "-1", lo que hace que tu proveedor sea nulo, deberías tener algo como: **public void eliminarNodo() { top = Proveedor.top; etc... }**, notese, que la variable **top** en **Proveedor** debe ser **static**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De lo que entiendo en tu código es que tienes un puntero que se llama `top` que comienza en -1, y supongo que a medida que vas ingresando elementos haces `top++`

Tu usas un `for` que no se que sentido puede tener además haces un `if (i == 0)` lo cual tiene aun menos sentido para mi.

Una `Pila` tiene al menos 2 funciones básicas

- `push` : agrega un nuevo elemento al final de la lista
- `pop`: Retorna el último elemento de la lista y lo saca de ella

En tu caso la función `push` debería ser algo como:

```
public void push(Proveedor p){
   top++;
   vector[top] = p;
}
```

Y el `pop`

```
public Proveedor pop(){
   if(top<0) return null;
   Proveedor aux =vector[top];
   vector[top]=null;
   top--;
   return aux;
}
```

Luego podrías tener otras funciones utilitarias como

`top` que retorna el último pero sin retirarlo

```
public Proveedor top(){
   if(top<0) return null;
   return vector[top];
}
```

`isEmpty` que comprueba si la lista está vacia o no

```
public bool isEmpty(){
   return top<0;
}
```

`size` que retorna la cantidad de elementos

```
public int size(){
   return top+1;
}
```

Comment: sinceramente no creí que fuera tan fácil jejeje

Comment: oye te molesta si me aclaras esta duda, es que mi proyecto me pide imitar el comportamiento de una pila. entonces me pide eliminar el último elemento de la pila, pero tengo la duda de si realmente el último elemento es el primero que ingreso a la pila y es el que esta hasta el fondo (el ultimo de abajo) o es el último elemento en ingresar a la pila, que sería el primero en salir. ?

Comment: @IsaacNewton En una Pila el último que entra es el primero que sale, imagina unos cuadernos apilados en tu escritorio, los dejas un arriba de otro y el primero que puedes sacar es el último que pusiste, este comportamiento se llama LIFO (last in, first out). En una Pila "pura" que es lo que tu estas viendo académicamente no hay más vueltas que esto que te digo.

Comment: entonces mi método para eliminar está mal?

Comment: porque si me piden eliminar el ultimo elemento ese seria el primero entonces ?

Comment: @IsaacNewton Yo creo que te estas confundiendo porque tu dentro la pila, la estas implementado con un `array` y estas imaginando el array. Pero eso da lo mismo, tu podrías tener elementos desordenados, de arriba hacia abajo o de cualquier forma, mientras el ultimo ingresado (push) sea el primero en salir (pop) es una pila

Comment: Si quieres lo conversamos en el chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146964/yssef

Comment: pero el último en salir debería ser el primero?                                                             si tengo 1 2 3 5 7 y me piden eliminar el ultimo entonces ese seria 1  o 7 ?

Comment: @IsaacNewton El 7

Comment: a ok ok, entonces no estoy mal

Comment: bueno muchas gracias por haberme ayudado